# How do I limit the range of my draggable SVG shape?

Tags: javascript, svg, draggable

I have an SVG slider that I've been working on ... please [**see it on jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mOrloff/ucnyz/3/).
I would like to limit the range of my sliders.

My JS started out as found on [**this picker**](http://phrogz.net/svg/complex-plane-picker.xhtml) (thanks to @Phrogz), then I poked and prodded at it until I was able to strip it down to its current state.
The sliders are working great, but I can really use some guidance on adding the limitations.

For example, I'd like **slider_1** (the slider on the left) to be limited to the area in front of the blue rectangle.
JS is still pretty unnatural for me, so I'd appreciate any and all feedback.

Thanks-a-bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try throwing something like this into your `move` functions:

```
var limitLower = 0;
var limitUpper = 20;
if ( x < limitLower || x > limitUpper ) {
    return;
}
```

Here's a fiddle with the above code inserted for slider1: http://jsfiddle.net/ucnyz/4/

Comment: good solution, but limits of 24,100 match the blue rectangle better.

Comment: Wasn't exactly sure what the OP meant by "in front of" the blue rectangle. Either way, this should be enough to get him/her on the right track.

Comment: PERFECT! ... and yes, 24,100 matches better, and this is definitely enough to get me on the right track :) Thanks a bunch